# Vb.net regex finding a pattern after 5 spaces and 2 characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to work on this regex pattern and match below examples. There are 5 spaces after Rx which I have tried to use `"  *",` for but no luck.

`("RX,"  *",\w\w(\w\w\w\w))`

```
1)     18468.0  Rx     1CEBF900  8  02 00 00 80 00 01 01 FF - ' should match EBF9 
2)     18468.6  Rx     18FD4000  8  FF FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF - 'should match FD40
ETC . . .
```

Comment: This looks like fixed-width text. You're probably much better off using `Substring()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression seems to work:

```
Rx\s{5}\S{2}(.{4})
```

```vb
Function GetValue(line As String) As String
    Dim regex As New Regex("Rx {5}\S{2}(.{4})")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(line)
    If match.Success Then Return match.Groups(1).Value
    Return Nothing        
End Function
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/yY3xXX

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pattern that seems to extract the specific data you're seeking. It was generated and tested via [RegExr](https://www.regexr.com/).

Search Pattern: `/(Rx {5}[0-9A-F]{2})([0-9A-F]{4})/g`;
List/Replace Pattern: `$2`

Description: the first capture group specifies "Rx", five spaces, and two hexadecimal range characters; the second capture group specifies the next four hexadecimal range characters.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following regex and vb.net code. This will result `EBF9` and `FD40` values in output. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/EIBJxo/1) for used regex in following.

Regex used for solution is:`(?<=\s+Rx\s{5}.{2})\S+(?=\d{2})`.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
    
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(?<=\s+Rx\s{5}.{2})\S+(?=\d{2})")
        Dim match As Match = regex.Match("18468.0  Rx     1CEBF900  8  02 00 00 80 00 01 01 FF")
        If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine("RESULT: [{0}]", match)
        End If        

        Dim match1 As Match = regex.Match("18468.6  Rx     18FD4000  8  FF FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF")
        If match1.Success Then
            Console.WriteLine("RESULT: [{0}]", match1.Value)
        End If
        
    End Sub
End Module
```

***Explanation of regex:***

```
(?<=\s+Rx\s{5}.{2}) ##Positive look behind to make sure Rx followed 
                    ##by 5 spaces followed by 2 any characters present.
\S+                 ##matching all non-spaces here.
(?=\d{2})           ##Making sure they are followed by 2 digits.
```

Also I have taken both of your sample lines in 2 different variables just to show 2 lines output.